# Finding first pair of numbers in array that sum to value

Tags: python, optimization, memoization

Im trying to solve the following Codewars problem: https://www.codewars.com/kata/sum-of-pairs/train/python

Here is my current implementation in Python:

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    right = float("inf")

    n = len(ints)
    m = {}
    dup = {}

    for i, x in enumerate(ints):
        if x not in m.keys():
            m[x] = i # Track first index of x using hash map. 
        elif x in m.keys() and x not in dup.keys():
            dup[x] = i

        for x in m.keys():
            if s - x in m.keys():
                if x == s-x and x in dup.keys():
                    j = m[x]
                    k = dup[x]
                else:
                    j = m[x]
                    k = m[s-x]


                comp = max(j,k)
                if comp < right and j!= k:
                    right = comp


    if right > n:
        return None

    return [s - ints[right],ints[right]]
```

The code seems to produce correct results, however the input can consist of array with up to 10 000 000 elements, so the execution times out for large inputs. I need help with optimizing/modifying the code so that it can handle sufficiently large arrays.

Comment: Am I missing something do you have a syntax error on line 11? I believe it should be `elif x in m.keys() and x not in dup.keys()` instead.

Comment: @Pame answered your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code inefficient for large list test cases so it gives timeout error. Instead you can do:

```
def sum_pairs(lst, s):
    seen = set()
    for item in lst:
        if s - item in seen:
            return [s - item, item]
        seen.add(item)
```

We put the values in `seen` until we find a value that produces the specified sum with one of the `seen` values.
For more information go: [Referance link](https://coderbyte.com/algorithm/two-sum-problem)

Comment: I tested it and it works nicely. But how does it not time out if theres say 10 000 000 elements in the list, and no pair of values equal to sum?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code:

```py
def sum_pairs(lst, s):
    c = 0
    while c<len(lst)-1:
        if c != len(lst)-1: 
            x= lst[c]
            spam = c+1
            while spam < len(lst):
                nxt= lst[spam]
                if nxt + x== s:
                    return [x, nxt]
                spam += 1
        else:
            return None
        c +=1
lst = [5, 6, 5, 8]
s = 14
print(sum_pairs(lst, s))
```

Output:

```py
[6, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer unfortunately still times out, even though it's supposed to run in O(n^3) (since it is dominated by the sort, the rest of the algorithm running in O(n)). I'm not sure how you can obtain better than this complexity, but I thought I might put this idea out there.

```
def sum_pairs(ints, s):
    ints_with_idx = enumerate(ints)

    # Sort the array of ints
    ints_with_idx = sorted(ints_with_idx, key = lambda (idx, num) : num)

    diff = 1000000
    l = 0
    r = len(ints) - 1

    # Indexes of the sum operands in sorted array
    lSum = 0
    rSum = 0

    while l < r:
        # Compute the absolute difference between the current sum and the desired sum
        sum = ints_with_idx[l][1] + ints_with_idx[r][1]
        absDiff = abs(sum - s)
        if absDiff < diff:
            # Update the best difference
            lSum = l
            rSum = r
            diff = absDiff
        elif sum > s:
            # Decrease the large value
            r -= 1
        else:
            # Test to see if the indexes are better (more to the left) for the same difference
            if absDiff == diff:
                rightmostIdx = max(ints_with_idx[l][0], ints_with_idx[r][0])
                if rightmostIdx < max(ints_with_idx[lSum][0], ints_with_idx[rSum][0]):
                    lSum = l
                    rSum = r
            # Increase the small value
            l += 1

    # Retrieve indexes of sum operands
    aSumIdx = ints_with_idx[lSum][0]
    bSumIdx = ints_with_idx[rSum][0]

    # Retrieve values of operands for sum in correct order
    aSum = ints[min(aSumIdx, bSumIdx)]
    bSum = ints[max(aSumIdx, bSumIdx)]

    if aSum + bSum == s:
        return [aSum, bSum]
    else:
        return None
```